# NodeJS provided callback function returns 'callback is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, jquery-callback

I'm calling a function `scandir()` with a parameter to pass and a callback function. Once that functions complete I call that callback, however I get `callback is not a function`. I don't understand where i'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Script file:

```
scan_dir(working_dir, function(items){
    console.log('done');
    dir_items = items;
    console.log('items', dir_items);
});
```

Functions file:

```
var scan_dir_count = 0;

function scan_dir(path, callback){
    scan_dir_count++;

    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files){ 
        files.forEach(function(item, index){
            //console.log(index, item);
            if (fs.lstatSync(path + '/' + item).isDirectory()){
                files.push(path + '/' + scan_dir(path + '/' + item));
            }
        });
        scan_dir_count--;

        if (scan_dir_count == 0){
            console.log('end');
            callback(files);
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Updated to 4castles response. No longer returns any errors, but the callback function doesn't seem to be firing...

```
var scan_dir_count = 0;

function scan_dir(path, callback){
    scan_dir_count++;

    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files){ 
        files.forEach(function(item, index){
            //console.log(index, item);
            if (fs.lstatSync(path + '/' + item).isDirectory()){
                scan_dir(path + '/' + item, function(data){ files.push(item + '/' + data); });
            }
        });
        scan_dir_count--;

        if (scan_dir_count == 0){
            console.log('end');
            console.log(files);
            callback(files);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You're calling `scan_dir(path + '/' + item)` without a callback.

Comment: Oh of course, makes sense. So i've added `function(){}` but that seems a bit janky, not only that but the final callback doesn't seem to fire, the `console.log('end')` does however the `console.log('items', item)` doesn't.

Comment: That's strange. Well you probably want to put the `files.push` in the callback. Since `scan_dir` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the function does not fire ? I gave the address of a sample  folder  and it seems to be working ok :

I got this as response :

end
[ 'config.html', 'config.html~', 'config.js', 'config.js~' ]
done
items [ 'config.html', 'config.html~', 'config.js', 'config.js~' ]